# Android Browser crash on file input save

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, browser, crash

The Android browser crashes in a very simple scenario (I am testing on Galaxy S3, Android 4.1.2):

I have a page with a text input and a file input (you can test it here http://jsbin.com/agugit/1/)

```
<input type="text" name="test"/>
<br />
<br />
file<input type="file" />
```

If you focus the text field first, and then hit the 'next' key from the keyboard, the native file picker pops up.

Pick a file, or take a picture, and the next thing that happens is the browser freezing.

If instead you are focusing the file input dirrectly (by tapping, not by using 'next'), everything works just fine.

I have tried different workarounds but none found.

Any help or ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I have found on Android is to make every file input disabled by default (so that it is skipped from tab order navigation) and listen the 'tap' event, so that when tap occurs, I focus the field programatically, so that the file picker pops up.

After the focus, and a delay of say 500 ms, make the field disabled again.

Any other ideas are still welcomed.